# C# WinForm, DataGridViewCell GetFormattedValue is called too frenquently

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm learning to customize DataGridViewCell, I want my user can only input string that can be parsed to DateTime, otherwise the Value is set to 2222-2-22(just for test). I have subclassed from DataGridViewTextBoxCell to make things simple. I have overridden the SetValue and GetFormattedValue method.

The code is as following. However, in runtime, the GetFormattedValue method is called very frequently, and the

> try (Convert.ToDateTime) catch

has some performance problem. I think my code has some problem.

Please kindly check is for me, thanks a lot.

```
class WMZDGVDateCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

    protected override bool SetValue(int rowIndex, object value)
    {
        if (value != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------in SetValue-------" + value.ToString());

        DateTime valueAsDate;
        try
        {
            valueAsDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
        }
        catch
        {

            valueAsDate = new DateTime(2222, 2, 22);
            //throw;
        }

        return base.SetValue(rowIndex, valueAsDate.ToShortDateString());
    }


    protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        if (value != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------in GetFormattedValue-------" + value.ToString());

        DateTime valueAsFormatted;
        try
        {
            valueAsFormatted = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
        }
        catch
        {
            valueAsFormatted = new DateTime(2222, 2, 22);
        }

        return base.GetFormattedValue(valueAsFormatted.ToShortDateString(), rowIndex, ref cellStyle, valueTypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter, context);
    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would avoid using `Try` `Catch` blocks unless they are necessary since they can affect your program's performance. Here is something I came up with:

```
class WMZDGVDateCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    protected override bool SetValue(int rowIndex, object value)
    {
        if (value != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------in SetValue-------" + value.ToString());

        DateTime valueAsDate;
        if (value != null && DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out valueAsDate))
        {
            //succeeded
        }
        else
        {
            valueAsDate = new DateTime(2222, 2, 22);
            //failed
        }

        return base.SetValue(rowIndex, valueAsDate.ToShortDateString());
    }


    protected override object GetFormattedValue(object value, int rowIndex, ref DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter valueTypeConverter, System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter formattedValueTypeConverter, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        if (value != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("------in GetFormattedValue-------" + value.ToString());

        DateTime valueAsFormatted;
        if (value != null && DateTime.TryParse(value.ToString(), out valueAsFormatted))
        {
            //succeeded
        }
        else
        {
            valueAsFormatted = new DateTime(2222, 2, 22);
            //failed
        }

        return base.GetFormattedValue(valueAsFormatted.ToShortDateString(), rowIndex, ref cellStyle, valueTypeConverter, formattedValueTypeConverter, context);
    }
}
```

Another thing you could do is use the `DataGridView` `CellEndEdit` event, check if the value is valid and, if not, change it to your default value.